# How to test a method in Jasmine if the code in `beforeEach` is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm trying to write some tests with Jasmine, but now have a problem if there are some code is asynchronous in `beforeEach`.

The sample code looks like:

```
describe("Jasmine", function() {

    var data ;

    beforeEach(function(){
        console.log('Before each');
        getSomeDataFromRemote(function(res){
            data = res;
        });
    });

    it("test1", function() {
        expect(data).toBe(something);
        console.log('Test finished');
    });

});
```

You can see, in the `beforeEach`, I want to get some data from remote, and assign it to the `data` asynchronously.

But in the `test1`, when I try to verify:

```
 expect(data).toBe(something);
```

The data is `undefined`, because `getSomeDataFromRemote` has not finished yet.

How to fix it?

Comment: I know Mocha can do async setup, but I'm less familiar with Jasmine. Have you tried using the [async spec constructs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) in your `beforeEach`? The docs only show them being used inside specs, but they might work in the `beforeEach` too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just like the async stuff within an `it` you can use the `runs` and `waitsFor` in your beforeEach:

```
define( 'Jasmine' , function () {
    var data ;

    beforeEach(function(){
        runs( function () {
            getSomeDataFromRemote(function(res){
                data = res;
            });
        });

        waitsFor(function () { return !!data; } , 'Timed out', 1000);
    });

    it("test1", function() {
        runs( function () {
              expect(data).toBe(something);
        });
    });
});
```

Although I'm going to assume that it's because this was test code I think you should probably have the `getSomeDataFromRemote` call inside your `it` as that's actually what you're testing ;)

You can see some larger examples in some tests I've written for an async API here: https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js/blob/f8a1c331a20e14e286e3f21ff8cea8c2e3e57be6/tests/public/specs/open-db.js

Comment: waitsFor and runs have been discontinued in Jasmine. Now on, You can use done(). Hope this helps - http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Answer (score 16):

**[Jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)**

Be careful because in the new Jasmine 2.0 this is going to change and it will be *mocha* style. You have to use `done()` function in `beforeEach()` and `it()`. For example, imagine you want to test if a page exists and is not empty, in a LAMP server, using jQuery `$.get`. First you need to add jQuery to the `SpecRunner.html` file, and in your `spec.js` file:

```
describe('The "index.php" should', function() {
    var pageStatus;
    var contents;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        $.get('views/index.php', function (data, status) {
            contents = data;
            pageStatus = status;
            done();
        }).fail(function (object, status) {
            pageStatus = status;
            done();
        });
    });

    it('exist', function(done) {
        expect(status).toBe('success');
        done();
    });

    it('have content', function(done) {
        expect(contents).not.toBe('');
        expect(contents).not.toBe(undefined);
        done();
    });
});
```

As you can see, you pass the function `done()` as a parameter for `beforeEach()` and `it()`. When you run the test, `it()` won't be launched until `done()` has been called in `beforeEach()` function, so you are not going to launch the expectations until you have the response from the server.

**The page exists**

If the page exists we capture the status and the data from the response of the server, and we call `done()`. Then we check if the status is "success" and if the data is not empty or undefined.

**The page does not exist**

If the page does not exist we capture the status from the response of the server, and we call `done()`. Then we check if the status is not "success" and if the data is empty or undefined (that must be because the file does not exist).

Comment: `done()` also holds true for projects such as [minijasminenode](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode)

Comment: i found beforeAll does not support async style.the spec below will run before the beforeAll call the "done"

Comment: Why is ```done``` passed into the ```it``` functions and called?  What could go wrong if they were omitted from the ```it```?

Comment: It appears in Jasmine documentation. I'm doing some tests and it seems that if you use `done`, you stop the execution until you call `done()`. If you remove it from the `beforeEach`, the test fails because you launch the `it` before resolving the `GET`. It seems to have no effect in the `it`. Here you have the example I have in [GitHub](https://github.com/timbergus/jasmine-async-test).

Comment: thanks @Timbergus, that is what I was wondering.   Its clear to me how (& why) ```done``` is used with ```beforeEach()```, it was the simultaneous use in ```it()``` that had me puzzled.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I typically stub the asynchronous call to respond immediately.

I'm not sure if you've seen it or not, but [here](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) is some documentation about asynchronous testing with Jasmine.

Comment: I just checked your link, but still don't know how to do it in my case.

Comment: You wrap your `getSomeDataFromRemote` call in a `runs` function, as well as the expectations. You use `waits` to provide some timeout that's long enough before your expectation runs. It's fiddly for sure, and can cause random failures. This is why i just stub the call to return immediately. [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) also provides some help in the ajax stubbing area if you prefer something further from the metal.

Comment: thank you, `runs` and `waitsFor` is exactly what I'm looking for. But since @Slace gave me an working and detail example, I have to accept his answer. Sorry~

Comment: @x1a4 when you say that id's "fiddly" and can cause "random failures", are you referring to the inherent race condition in using waits instead of waitsFor, or are you saying that runs, waits, and waitsFor functionality is buggy in jasmine?

Comment: @snapfractalpop the race condition